# How to start xscreensaver on startup

Tags: suspend

xscreensaver is safe to run with some settings that won't change Elementary OS look and feel: choose your screensaver and check he doesn't do so and save those settings.

Once done, you'll notice that you can't just add it on startup, it requires a script to run properly (otherwise it's window will popup on startup).

Note: I installed it because on my system, suddenly my machine wouldn't suspend anymore, requiring the need to install xscreensaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Applications > System Settings >  Applications > Startup Tab > add > Type in custom command

and there type: xscreensaver -nosplash